# What is unit number in /boot/device.hints FreeBSD configuration

Tags: freebsd, serial-console, terminology

In [device.hints](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?device.hints) FreeBSD manpage we have following description:

> A device hint line    looks like:
>
> ```
>   hint.driver.unit.keyword="value"
> ```
>
> where `driver` is the name of a device driver, `unit` is the unit number, and
> keyword is    the keyword of the hint.  The keyword may be:

I confused about `unit` term. What unit ?

Is unit refer to number of COM port ?

Why author used this term ?

Comment: Yes. It is the number of the port, e.g. 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: @RichardSmith You should make that an answer, not a comment.